# Messenger Postback button doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, messenger

Messenger Postback button doesn't trigger a post request to NodeJs server.

NodeJs running on CentOS 7. Tried to dump every request to server and got nothing.

```
// request object
{
    attachment: {
        type: "template",
            payload : {
            template_type: "button",
            text: "Welcome you here!",
            buttons: [{
                type: "postback",
                title: "Do tests",
                payload: "do_test"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Server should receive a POST request but I've got nothing...

> Got it! Postback button doesn't work in the same way as Quick Reply buttons. It doesn't send a message in its request. I had mistaken at this point.

Comment: Please share the code where you pass this object into the request.

Comment: Ah I've got it. This problem was caused by my mistake.

Comment: I should have know that Postback button sends a postback event instead of message. Thank you for your reply...

Cheer!